# Background image slideshow not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using following theme for one of website ([click here](http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/squadfree/)). This theme come with one background image and i modified this to multiple background images for 'section' tag `<section id="intro" class="intro"></section>`

This script doesn't wok properly as it show black screen in between image at time.

codepen [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doXjjX)

```
<!-- Section: intro -->
<section id="intro" class="intro">

    <div class="slogan">

        <h1><span class="text_color">WELCOME TO SQUAD</span> </h1>

    </div>
    <div class="page-scroll">
        <div class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
        <a href="#latest-tabs" class="btn btn-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Section: intro -->
```

I am using a trick and showing all these image also in another div with it display property, this way helped to to resolve black screen between image transition as all image are cached if i am not wrong if i dont put these image in a hidden div then each image takes time to download.

```
 <div class="background-images" style="display: none !important;">
            <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/squadfree/img/bg1.jpg" />
            <img src="http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/12/859698-nature-background.jpg" />
            <img src="http://interest.ge/inter/app/interest/data/uploaded/20140923140402202316338_photo.jpg" />
            <img src="http://interest.ge/inter/app/interest/data/uploaded/20140923140344524813450_photo.jpg" />
            <img src="http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/15/897490-stunning-nature-background.jpg" />
        </div>
```

Overall you will notice that it breaks, for some reason it some works well in other browser other than FF.

i need to fix this or need another script which can show slid show for a container div as shown in this example and works well with fadein fadeout effect

Comment: Looking for something like **[here](http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fullscreen-background-image-plugins/)**??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that images are being downloaded via a GET request each time JS switches them. Try to cache them somehow so you can save some time on a get/redirect requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the black screen is caused by the image source, if you look the image source when black screen occurs, it doesn't show an image, and if you navigate to that source through the browser, it gives you an redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused due to incorrect image source...
For ex. this URL is not redirecting to any image..

"http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/15/897490-stunning-nature-background.jpg"